# Error "No process is on the other end of the pipe"

Tags: sql-server-2005

I've just re-installed sql server 2005 on one of our testing servers (w2k3) after a fatal failure.
After finishing with the installation I'm trying to access remotely the server through sql management studio.

I'm getting

> "The client was unable to establish a connection because an error during (etc, etc, etc).... No process is on the other end of the pipe"

I went ahead and using surface area configuration I selected "Using both TCP/IP and named pipes" on the server

After doing this the error changed to

> "Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding"

The remote connections area enabled, not sure what else to check. Could you help me to troobleshoot?

Thanks!

Comment: Check your firewall rules on the client and server.  Make sure you allow SQL Server traffic.  Also, ensure SQL Server is actually running and didn't die with an error message in the event log after initially started.

Comment: @Eric J. thanks for your answer. I can access the sql server locally and everything looks good. The problem is when I access remotely. I'll check about the firewall, although I'm not very positive. I've re-installed the sql server on the same machine It was working fine for years so firewall rules should be fine.

Comment: @Eric J. You were right, the problem was the firewall. If you add your comment as an answer, I'll mark this question as resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> 1) You might explicitly use "np:"prefix which ask for connect through
>   named pipe and specify FQDN/LoopbackIP/IPAddress as server name in the
>   connection string.
>
> 2) You might use FQDN/IPAddress/LoopbackIP to
>   connect to the server.
>
> To resolve 1) and 2), you can specify
>    instead of FQDN/IPADress/LoopbackIP.

Taken from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2005/12/22/506607.aspx).

Comment: I'd like to connect to the server as I always did: using the machine name + user name + password. Thanks!

Comment: Have you made sure that `TCP/IP` is enabled?

Comment: +1 since your method allowed me to make a connection. I checked and TCP/IP seems to be enabled. I verified this on SQL Server Configuration Manager.